# Algorithm Running Time

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

Given an algorithm with a running time $$T(n)=5T(n/2)+n^2$$

So the number of nodes at a depth $i$ would be: $5^i$

The input size for each node at $i$ would be: $n/2^i$

Agreed.

Then it states that the work at a depth $i$ is: $5^i \times (n/2^i)^2$

My understanding is that it should be the #nodes at a given depth times the input size for each node.

Why has the input size been squared in working out the total work for a given depth? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The squaring comes from the $n^2$ term in your recurrence. At each depth you actually only count these $n^2$ terms.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand; what if, hypothetically, the $n^2$ term was simply $n$. What would the work at a depth i be now?

Comment: You tell me. I'm not sure you understand what "work" means here. It means the time the algorithm spends at the given level. It depends both on the input size as well as on the algorithm. It doesn't measure the total amount of input bits processed.

Comment: If I had 15 points I'd give you a +1. Thanks for the help